# converting a signal back and forth with trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, matlab, trigonometric-series, octave

I'm trying to convert a signal back and forth using trigonometric functions. In the example below:

- 1) start off with a cos signal
- 2) convert the signal to a secant signal
- 3) would like to convert the secant signal back to the
  original cosine signal using Trig. (Is this possible?)

I know sec=1/cos I was trying to see if simple algebra would get the original signal back but it looks like my understanding of Trig is lacking, as you can see in the third plot below it doesn't go back to the original cos signal which is what I'm trying to do.

And please don't post just use **cos (x) or 1/y2.** This is a simple example showing what I'm trying to do, the real code is about 500 lines with multiple functions that it calls.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to get back to the original signal using Trig and matlab/octave

Here's the example matlab / octave code below:

```
clear all, clf
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y = cos(x); % 
subplot(3,1,1); 
plot(x,y)
title('original signal')

y2 =1./cos(x);  % secant
subplot(3,1,2); 
plot(x,y2)
title('converted signal')

y3 =sec(y2).*sec(y2);  % this section is incorrect not sure how to fix it
subplot(3,1,3); 
plot(x,y3)
title('back to original cos signal from secant')
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, but I can't comprehend what you're doing, this just seems like nonsense. Why are you expecting to get a cosine curve back? Compositions of trigonometric functions are not trigonometric functions, but are more complicated objects obtainable via the Jacobi-Anger relations.

Comment: In effect, $\sec ^2(\cos (x))\neq\cos(x)$.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus yes I know it's incorrect, that's why I labelled it incorrect and posted a plot of it.  I'm trying to get the cos signal back by using the data values in y2 and Trig / matlab code

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't just use `1/y2`. If that's not what you're looking for, then I don't understand what you mean by "get the cos signal back", because using `1/y2` is exactly what it means to get it back.

Comment: In essence, I don't understand how you're reconciling the two statements "using trig and Matlab code to get the cos signal back" and "don't post just use cos (x) or 1/y2", since they contradict each other. The amount of lines of other unrelated code you're using is irrelevant.

Comment: You just have to ensure that $n\pi/2\notin$ your linspace for any integer $n$, for the obvious overflow reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `y3=cos(asec(y2))` if you want `y3` to equal `y`. You current method is

$$
\cos(x) = \sec^2(\sec(x)) = { {1} \over {\cos^2( 1/\cos(x) )} },
$$

which is incorrect. You first need to to get the argument that gives you the value of `y2`:

$$
x = \sec^{-1}(y_2).
$$

This of course then leads to $y_3 = \cos( \sec^{-1} ( \sec(x) ) ) = \cos(x) = y$.